# Cannot get Q to work in browser side by including with script

Tags: javascript, html, promise, q

so I have tried q.min.js , q-master, and q.js from https://github.com/kriskowal/q/tree/v1...

In the head part of my HTML file I have-

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/inc/js/veud/q-1/q.js'></script>
```

which is being loaded correctly as I am not getting a file not found error.

In my body I have -

```
<script>
        var deferred = Q.defer();
</script>
```

however I keep getting the error -

```
ReferenceError : Q is not defined.
```

I have tried just using defer() without the Q but likewise I get

```
Reference Error: defer is not defined.
```

Have tried q too and like I said I tried it with multiple q javascript files.

It was working when I required it as a module in node.js but I really need it to work on the client / browser side now...

any idea on why this is not working?

BY THE WAY-

I am also getting this strange error -

```
SyntaxError: missing } after function body
```

that is saying that the q.js file is missing a } at the end of it, however, it is there! and I havent altered q.js at all!

any help is appreciated.

Comment: what browser are you using? try downloading the latest release v1.5.1 and then got to `examples/async-generators` and open `0.html` does the red cube move.

Comment: Im using an older firefox, and when I try to load 0.html firefox crashes however it worked when I loaded with chrome...

Comment: however I am still getting errors when I load my html file in chrome, Q is not defined, and before that Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected End of input which is pointing to the end of the q.js file the return Q; line